# Paypal Button send JSESSIONID to Spring security Backend

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security, paypal

I am trying to integrate the Paypal checkout button with my Spring Boot Backend. I have managed to get it working the only problem being as follows:

Because paypal makes a callback to the Backend once the payment has been authorized, the jsessionid is lost (aka not present) This id is used by Spring Security to determine the logged in user's information. When I'm trying to find out what user payed (and continue with my business logic knowing the payment has been approved), Spring security sees the user as `anonymous`.

I could just pass the value of the `JSESSIONID` cookie as a parameter, but that wouldn't get me very far, because afaik the sessions are managed by the container and I couldn't map a `JSESSIONID` to a username. How could I find out, in the backend, which user just made a payment?

This is basically the code I'm using for the button:

```
paypal.Button.render({
  env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

  commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

  style: {
    color: 'gold',
    size: 'small'
  },

  payment: function(data, actions) {
    // Set up a url on your server to create the payment
    var CREATE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/payment/generate';

    // Make a call to your server to set up the payment
    return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log("PAYMENT: ", res);
        return res.paymentID;
      });
  },

  onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    // Set up a url on your server to execute the payment
    var EXECUTE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/payment/execute';

    // Set up the data you need to pass to your server
    var data = {
      paymentID: data.paymentID,
      payerID: data.payerID
    };

    // Make a call to your server to execute the payment
    return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
      .then(function (res) {
        window.alert('Payment Complete!');
      });
  }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

I can also provide code for the Backen if it is needed.